# Is it bad practice to overload your main method?

Tags: java

I am aware of the limitations of it, but if I only intend on having a class, say, for example

```
public class GUIWindow
{
    static JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        theGUI.setSize(900, 600);
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theGUI.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(Object obj)
    {
        String[] array = new String[1];

        main(array);

        theGUI.setTitle(obj.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        String[] array = new String[1];

        main(array);

        theGUI.setTitle(null);
    }
}
```

that I can call to create a default GUI window of a certain size for the testing of multiple applications is it an alright thing to do?

Comment: you do realize none of them are not valid main methods right ??, what exactly do you wanna achieve here ?

Comment: Java will never call your other methods, are you planning on calling them yourself (in other parts of your code) ?

Comment: Bad for code readability, since java will never call other than the first one, why not just rename the other ones?

Comment: Using "main" method name for non-main methods is evil. A better solution is to rename them somehow else ("run", "init" or so) and call the appropriate one from the "real and unique main".

Comment: *Is it bad practice to overload your main method?* it is evil just like naming your class `class ___ {}` is, provided you are not working on code obfuscation !!!

Comment: This may be relevant: [The Hidden Dangers of Method Overloading](https://www.yegor256.com/2023/08/01/method-overloading.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`public static void main(Sting[] args)` is the only entry point JVM would recognize.
You could add other overloads (not overrides) of `main`, but these will lack that special meaning. It feels inconsistent and thus misleading.

If you want polymorphic instantiation of your main class, just add an independent family of methods for this. Don't mix it up with one predefined special method.

Answer (score 1):

The main method `public static void main(String args[])` should be used to set up your program and verify that the incoming arguments to your program are valid.  Anything else is usually considered bad practice.  This includes "overloading" your main method.

That being said, if you are just doing toy examples, or testing, do whatever you want in your main methods.